# How to extract hour, minutes and seconds from a DATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select cast(max_bid_ts as TIMESTAMP) from my_table;
```

I cast the `max_bid_ts` because it was a double and I wanted to be a `TMESTAMP`. This query returns something like this

```
2016-04-21 12:41:46.313999872
```

I only want the hour:minutes:seconds part. In this case would be 12:41:46. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: I would use `SELECT max_bid_ts::time FROM my_table`, or use `TO_CHAR()` to truncate the time part too.

Answer (score 23):

Try something like this:

```
select to_char(YourTimeStampField,'HH:MI:SS') from YourTable
```

And if you want a 24-hour time format, try this:

```
select to_char(YourTimeStampField,'HH24:MI:SS') from YourTable
```

Another way would be:

```
select YourTimeStampField::time from YourTable
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use: `select to_char(YourTimeStampField,'HH24:MI:SS') from YourTable`. Change `HH24:MM:SS` by `HH24:MI:SS`. Enjoy!

Comment: Indeed, beware: in Postgres, `MM` = "month number (01-12)" and `MI` = "minute (00-59)". [See the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE).

Answer (score 2):

```
select to_char(sysdate,'HH:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Comment: For Postgres Use
`select to_char(sysdate,'HH:MI:SS') from dual;`

Comment: In PostgreSQL that yields `ERROR:  relation "dual" does not exist`. Your solution does work for an Oracle data (not MySQL). I really wonder why one needs the `dual` table when only a function and a global variable is used.