# Calculate the only necessary difference and Group by between two Timestamps in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, timestamp-with-timezone

I see similar question but didn't find helpful answer for my problem.
I have one query:

```
    select au.username
        ,ej.id as "job_id"
        ,max(ec."timestamp") as "last_commit"
        ,min(ec."timestamp") as "first_commit"
        ,age(max(ec."timestamp"), min(ec."timestamp")) as "diff as age"
        ,to_char(age(max(ec."timestamp")::timestamp, min(ec."timestamp")::timestamp),'HH:MI:SS') as "diff as char"
        ,et.id as "task_id"
from table and etc..
```

And that my output(Sorry for picture but its best view):

[image]

So, as you can see I have timestamp with zones, and I trying calculate difference  between `last_commit` and `first_commit`. Within function `age` its goes well, but I need extract only hours and minutes from this subtraction. *N.B!* only hours and minutes not days for example `job_id=1` first row, the difference is 2 minutes and 42 seconds and where `job_id=2` second row, the difference is 2 hours and 2 minutes and 55 sec, not 16 days X 24 hours, I don't need calculate days. When I try `to_char` its return not exactly what I expect. Last two columns within green color in my picture, show what I expect and want. So for every row calculate difference between `last and first commit` included only hours and minutes (in other words calculate only time not dates) and calculate total sum by `task_id` as represent in last column in pic.
Thanks.

Comment: Share [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). i.e. share `create table script` & few `insert` statements for the table.

Comment: Take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/8339821. The question is about asking a qustion with SQL topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT age(max(ec."timestamp"), min(ec."timestamp")) - date_trunc('day', age(max(ec."timestamp"), min(ec."timestamp")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting a Timestamp type to just time, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850675/how-to-extract-hour-minutes-and-seconds-from-a-date).

The result of string SQL is:

```
select au.username
        ,ej.id as "job_id"
        ,max(ec."timestamp") as "last_commit"
        ,min(ec."timestamp") as "first_commit"
        ,(max(ec."timestamp")::time-min(ec."timestamp")::time) as "diff as age"
        ,to_char(age(max(ec."timestamp")::timestamp, min(ec."timestamp")::timestamp),'HH:MI:SS') as "diff as char"
        ,et.id as "task_id"
```

There are otres possible solutions working with timestamp, but this one i consider simple.